# Unable to import from gcm in flask

Tags: flask, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to implement and test gcm using flask on localhost. I have installed the `python-gcm` package by `sudo pip install python-gcm`, but I get an error saying

> import error : no module named gcm

I have written the gcm code in **run.py**, is it correct to write it in there?
I'm very new to flask please help..
My **run.py** is as follows :

```
#!flask/bin/python
from app import app
from gcm import *

gcm = GCM("My key is placed here")
data = {'the_message': 'You have x new friends', 'param2': 'value2'}

reg_id = 'registration id is placed here'

gcm.plaintext_request(registration_id=reg_id, data=data)
#app.run(debug=True)
app.run(host='127.0.0.1')
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your shebang, it looks like you've installed Flask inside a virtual environment. Since you're using `sudo` to install gcm, you're probably installing it to your system site-packages, not the virtual environment's.

```
$ source flask/bin/activate
$ python -m pip install python-gcm
```